# Signing Certificate APK

Tags: android, apk, keystore

If I transfer my android project to someone else, which files I need to send that person so she can sign the updates to the application without certificate errors?

Comment: send the keystore and credentials

Comment: What exactly is the keystore? .jks is the file?
and credentials, vc refers to alias and password?
developer java / android first time, rs

Comment: yes, thats what i mean

Comment: was what I sent, but the person is having the error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key nameapp from store "C:\Users\Paulo\nameapp.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect


I thought lacked send something more

Comment: he type the wrong password

Comment: she typed the wrong password..

Comment: I thought the same, at first, but then I even typed the password via remote access...